# What are allowed as literal characters in f-strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

In the BNF rules for the [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (f-strings):

```
f_string ::= (literal_char | "{{" | "}}" | replacement_field)*
...
literal_char ::= <any code point except "{", "}" or NULL>
```

What does it mean specifically regarding the NULL?

It looks like `f'\0'` is valid.

Comment: Null is an actual null byte *in the source code*. The *source code* `\0` is not a null byte, it represents one - the same way that the word `True` is not actually a boolean, but represents the truth value.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so `eval("f'\0'")` is supposed to fail, right?

Comment: @MarkRansom It does fail with ``ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`` for me.

Comment: In Python 3.7, having a null byte `\0` in an f-string results in "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes". So it means what it says: you can't have a null byte in there.

Comment: Great! It make sense for me now: it's the "literal" <NULL> in the source code. (This was a stupid confusion. But I wonder why NULL is specifically mentioned in f-string's BNF, but not other string literals' BNF.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed *code points* are `any code point except "{", "}" or NULL`.

The string `f"\0"` contains two code points `\` and `0`. They form an escape sequence that *represents* a null byte – just like `\n` represents a newline. This is similar to how the *source code* (a string) `True` represents the boolean true value (an object).
Notably, these representations are not the thing they represent. Placing `\0` in an f-string is fine because it is not a NULL itself.

```py
>>> # the source code representing a number is not the number
>>> source = "1337"
>>> eval(source) == source
False
```

---

Note that CPython and PyPy do not accept NULL bytes in source code to begin with.

Comment: The error message implies that the source itself cannot contain null characters, regardless of the syntax restrictions for f-strings.  Indeed `eval("'\0'")` produces the same error.

Comment: @MarkRansom You are right, I removed that part. None of ``eval``, ``import`` or ``ast`` seems to accept NULL bytes to begin with.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, it looks like the culprit is that [source code is internally handled as a ``char*`` in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d6155ee9d1b05946f951d0ba602b9f63810fe0f/Python/pythonrun.c#L1819).